# convery bufferedImage to jsp it success, but some seconds later it disapper

Tags: java, jsp

in java:

```
   //str is binary String from database
    //from Binary convert binary to byteArray           
    byte[] bytes = fromBinary(str);
    try {
        String name = "userAvatar";
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + name + "\"");
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
   }catch(Exception e){
    }
```

in jsp :

```
<img alt="" src="${basePath }action/download/img?action=..." >
```

when I click into this page the Image is shown correctly, but some seconds later, it disappear and console told me  **ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**

why?

Comment: Try `while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1)`, also make sure to close the stream `output.close();`

Comment: @Arvind thanks  when  I close the stream  it doesn`t exsit any more  at least up to now ,I should learn more about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the close statement:

```
  output.write(buffer, 0, length);
  output.close(); //missing
}
```